# How can we help users find answers to Git conflict resolution?

Tags: discussion

There's a basic problem that keeps popping up all the time for [Git questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=newest&pagesize=50), and it's of this form:

John Doe fetches/pulls/pushes/commits code in Git, and upon looking at the code, he finds a bunch of unresolved conflict markers in them:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:foo.txt
var x = "SHAZBOT!";
=======
var x = "SKADOOSH!"
>>>>>>> abc:foo.txt
```

John Doe says "WTF!?", and proceeds to ask on Stack Overflow [why his code got corrupted when he pulled](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17644247/1), or how to fix it when [Git added diff interface text to versioned file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638655/git-added-diff-interface-text-to-versioned-file), or [How can I stop tortoisegit from adding garbage to my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495723/how-can-i-stop-tortoisegit-from-adding-garbage-to-my-code).

I'm tired of having to constantly vote to close these questions as possible duplicates of [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git). Users are obviously having a hard time finding that question and its answers, and I can understand why: if you don't know that these

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:foo.txt
var x = "SHAZBOT!";
=======
var x = "SKADOOSH!"
>>>>>>> abc:foo.txt
```

are called "conflict markers" and are the result of unresolved "merge conflicts", how would you be able to search for them on Stack Overflow or Google?

I edited the question [Files pull from GitHub contain HEAD >>>>>>>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644247/files-pull-from-github-contain-head) to have the conflict marker in the title, in the hope that maybe if a user enters `HEAD >>> git` in the search box, they would find that their problem already has a question and answer, and I also tagged it with the [merge-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-conflict-resolution) tag, but are there better solutions?

Comment: And this isn't a problem only related to Git either

Comment: Users can't find it based on the question when the body text doesn't use any relevant keywords at all and is very generic. Whatever should be the canonical question should not be a guessing game from search results

Comment: I see that @random has been at working making a canonical answer: [Git merge left HEAD marks in my files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657315/git-merge-left-head-marks-in-my-files).

Comment: Here's another category of Git questions though, and it also pops up a lot, [line ending issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/1967986#1967986), like [this person's issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656846/git-same-directory-but-different-os-behaving-strange). It's always of the form "Git keeps telling me I have modified files when I haven't changed anything!?"